# What is the problem with this code? I'm new to programming and tried to solve this task about deposit calculations but I'm stuck at this for hours. C#

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace Deposit_calculator
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double depositedsum = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            double depositterm = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            double annualinterestpercentage = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            double sum = depositedsum + depositterm * ((depositedsum * annualinterestpercentage) /  12);
            Console.WriteLine(sum);
            
        }
    }
}
```

I was supposed to get this answer: 202.85 using this input:200
3
5.7
The formula is: amount = deposited amount + term of the deposit * ((deposited amount * annual interest rate ) / 12)

Comment: I don't have a chance to run your code yet, but let me guess, when you have a percentage of 5.7, you suppose to multiply by 0.057 instead 5.7. So try to divide the percentage by 100, Maybe this will solve your problem.

Comment: `0.057` not `5.7` the interest rate is a *percentage* which means out of 100

Comment: You said what answer you *expect*, but not what answer you *get*.

Comment: Do not use `double` for financial calculations. Use `decimal` instead.

Comment: Also: Write a small function that takes a prompt string as an arg and returns a `decimal` (assuming you change from `double` to `decimal`). It should prompt the user with the prompt string, then read the console into a string (`var response = Console.ReadLine();` and then use `decimal.TryParse(response, out var result);` to convert the result into a `decimal`. If the `TryParse` call fails (i.e. returns `false`), you can tell your user to be more careful and reprompt him/her again.  Using `.Parse` instead of `.TryParse` will cause an exception with incorrect input. Typos are not exceptional.

Comment: The lesson here ought to be: "Before writing any code, work out *in detail* what the program is supposed to do."  For math formulae, that means working out exactly what those formulae are.

Answer (score 1):

As per those that have already commented - percentage should be divided by 100, i.e.:

```
using System;

namespace Deposit_calculator
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double depositedsum = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            double depositterm = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            double annualinterestpercentage = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) / 100;
            double sum = depositedsum + depositterm * ((depositedsum * annualinterestpercentage) /  12);
            Console.WriteLine(sum);
            
        }
    }
}
```